# Angular nested ng-repeat class variable

Tags: angularjs, ng-class, angularjs-ng-class, angularjs-ng-class-even, angularjs-ng-class-odd

So I have a fairly complex angular table, and I have the repeating portion all good to go, but when I set a variable with `ng-class-even` and `ng-class-odd`, the variable doesn't seem to persist. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the scope of the `ng-repeat`, but I'm stumped.

My repeat looks something like:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="item in data.group" ng-class-even="color='red'" ng-class-odd="color='blue'">
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>            
    <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="inner in item.innerdata" ng-class="color">
        <td>{{inner.innername}}</td>
    </tr>
</tr>
```

So, I expect color to be set while the rows loop. Here's a [**Fiddle with the sample setup.**](http://jsfiddle.net/pvch63ko/)

Comment: @JsIsAwesome I think you're misunderstanding what the code is doing. In `ng-class-even`, it sets a variable called `color` to a value of `red`. Maybe I didn't name my variables well enough. I'm trying to use the variable of `color` in my `ng-class`, but it's only set by the last repeating item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ng-class-even` & `ng-class-odd` will look at the current `ng-repeat` $index object and decides which value should be given to class attribute.

> **`ng-class-even` / `ng-class-odd`**
>
> Takes an expression & the result of the evaluation can be a string
>   representing space delimited class names or an array.

Change mark up like below HTML

**Markup**

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="item in data.group" ng-init="$index%2==0?(color='blue'): (color='red')">
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>            
        <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="inner in item.innerdata" ng-class="color">
            <td>{{inner.innername}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pvch63ko/1/)**

**Update 1**

Better solution would be directly use `ng-class` to inner ng-repeat

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="item in data.group">
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>            
        <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="inner in item.innerdata" ng-class="$parent.$index%2 == 0? 'red': 'blue'">
            <td>{{inner.innername}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[**Updated 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/pvch63ko/3/)

**Update 2**

More accurate solution would be using `$even` or `$odd` object of `$parent`

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="item in data.group">
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>            
        <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="inner in item.innerdata" ng-class="$parent.$even? 'red': 'blue'">
            <td>{{inner.innername}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[**Update 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/pvch63ko/4/)

Comment: That works, and I'll accept it, but do you have an idea why `ng-class-even` would not set a variable like that?

Comment: `ng-class` even will directly needs the class value in string, they don't run any function..take a look at updated answer..which would be more efficient way

Comment: @Chad take a look at my answer I updated the answer..how ng-class-even and odd works